# Using private properties in React component

Tags: reactjs

The following code works; I receive no error and Web Storm's IDE is not freaking out.

Yet, I must have missed documentation on this.

```
export default class WidgetContainer extends React.Component {
    ....

 compListeners = [
    {name: "collapseWidget", action: this._widgetCollapse.bind(this)},
    {name: "goFullscreen", action: this._goFullScreen.bind(this)}
  ];

  componentDidMount() {
    this.compListeners.map(ev => {
      window.addEventListener(ev.name, ev.action, false)
    });
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.compListeners.map(ev => {
      window.removeEventListener(ev.name, ev.action, false)
    });
  }

    ....
}
```

Is it acceptable practice in react to declare **compListeners** like this? I save a lot of lines of code.

Comment: IMO..yes.. you can

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is perfectly acceptable in react to declare an array of object. What you have done with

```
compListeners = [
    {name: "collapseWidget", action: this._widgetCollapse.bind(this)},
    {name: "goFullscreen", action: this._goFullScreen.bind(this)}
  ];
```

is declare and array of objects with name and action properties.

with the `window.addEventListener()` you are just passing on parameter from the array the the above function as it needs so there is no problem.